# How can I get all column names into a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a project in SQL Server and I am trying to get all column names into a new column (each column name will become the values in the new column).

For example:

```
Student Teacher   Staff    
------------------------
John    Amy       ack  
Josh    Adam      cOk 
Jason   Johnny    Fuacn
```

Will be transformed to something like

```
Name    OCCUPATION    
--------------------
John    Student         
Josh    Student 
Jason   Student
Amy     Teacher
Adam    Teacher
Johnny  Teacher
ack     Staff
cOk     Staff
Fuacn   Staff
```

Many thanks for your help

Comment: Try [UNPIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Why is "Jason" staff?  What happened to "ack"?

Answer (score 2):

You can unpivot using `apply`:

```
select v.name, v.occupation
from t cross apply
     (values ('student', student), ('teacher', teacher), ('staff', staff)
     ) v(occupation, name)
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, but how can I put all names into column 'name'?

Comment: @songjosh . . . That is what this does.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option which will dynamically unpivot virtually any table or query using a bit of JSON and not Dynamic SQL.

**Note:** If not 2016+, there is an similar XML approach.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Student] varchar(50),[Teacher] varchar(50),[Staff] varchar(50))  
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('John','Amy','ack')
,('Josh','Adam','cOk')
,('Jason','Johnny','Fuacn')
 
Select [Name] = B.[Value]
      ,[Occupation] = B.[Key]
 From @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select [Key]
                      ,Value
                 From OpenJson((Select A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper )) 
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
Name    Occupation
John    Student
Amy     Teacher
ack     Staff
Josh    Student
Adam    Teacher
cOk     Staff
Jason   Student
Johnny  Teacher
Fuacn   Staff
```